# NestJS and Graphql mutation: DTO and CreateInput

Tags: graphql, nestjs, dto

I want to add an activity to a favorite table:

```
@Mutation(() => FavoriteDto)
@UseGuards(AuthGuard)
async createFavorite(
  @Context() context: any,
  @Args('createFavoriteInput') createFavoriteDto: CreateFavoriteInput,
): Promise<FavoriteDto> {
  const favorite = await this.favoriteService.create(
    context.user!.id,
    createFavoriteDto,
  );

  return this.favoriteMapper.convert(favorite);
}
```

CreateFavoriteInput should only have the id of the activity, the userId will be save with the current auth session like the following code bellow:

```
@InputType()
export class CreateFavoriteInput {
  @Field()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsMongoId()
  activityId!: string;
}
```

My DTO has the activity and

```
@ObjectType()
export class FavoriteDto {
  @Field()
  id!: string;

  @Field(() => ActivityDto)
  activity!: ActivityDto;
}
```

When I tried to generate types I have this error:

> Error 0: Cannot query field "activityId" on type "FavoriteDto". Did you mean "activity"?

How can I match my CreateFavoriteInput with my DTO ?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a misunderstanding between the data you expect and the data you return

```
@Mutation(() => FavoriteDto) // return type
```

Here FavoriteDto is the type you return from your `mutation`

So you can't query `activityId` as it's in your `CreateFavoriteInput` and not in `FavoriteDto`

In your client you can only query `id` and `activity` (assuming it's returned from your mutation). If you return an `activityId` you just have to replace `id` with `activityId` in FavoriteDto.

Also if you want to be consistent you should replace

```
  @Args('createFavoriteInput') createFavoriteDto: CreateFavoriteInput
```

with

```
  @Args('createFavoriteInput') createFavoriteInput: CreateFavoriteInput
```

So that it won't be confusing between DTO types and input types.

Comment: I'm learning graphql and mongodb. So there is no relation between the table activity and favorite ? I just have to save a favorite with an activity data ? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @etrix It depends on your graph. You can simply add an activityId in your favorite model using @Prop({ type: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId , ref: 'Activity' }); activityId: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId